# How to navigate to next page using selenium by finding the javscript URL within div

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Using `selenium` and `bs4` in Python, if I run the following code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)   # url = https://www.marathon.tokyo/2023/result/index.php, choose Men Marathon in first option, should show the 50 result entries on each page
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

then part of the course code is as follow:

```
<div class="fnav pager pagerBottom mb40">
<p class="taR">51～100／27927</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:page(1);">1</a></li><li><span>2</span></li><li><a href="javascript:page(3);">3</a></li><li><a href="javascript:page(4);">4</a></li><li><a href="javascript:page(5);">5</a></li><li><a href="javascript:page(6);">6</a></li><li><a href="javascript:page(7);">7</a></li> </ul>
</div>
```

This is essentially the navigation panel for going to different pages. How to locate the 'clickable' element, e.g. `"javascript:page(X);"`? I try the following

```
out = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.fnav li > a')
out.click()
```

But `out` seems to contain only the first clickable element, e.g. if I'm on page 1, it goes to page 2, if I'm on page 2, it goes to page 1. How to click on the 'next' page? Page 1 -> page 2 -> page 3 and so on?

Comment: XPATH of //a[contains(@href, 'page(x)')] oughta do it.